# What is the syntax behind the sorted argument?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

```
def bigSorting(unsorted):
   return sorted(unsorted, key=lambda s: (len(s), s))
```

I am trying to understand this solution I saw on "HackerRank". The example of unsorted list given is:

```
unsorted = ['1','200','150','2']
```

How does `key=lambda s: (len(s), s))` work?

Comment: It's sorting first by length, and then lexicographically among all the strings with the same length. This makes it equivalent to sorting numerically.

Comment: Are you asking how/what a `lambda` is, what passing arguments by name (e.g. `key=`) means, or what `sorted` is doing with that argument? Virtually all of those are either already answered here or described in the docs for `sorted`, but you need to be clear on what is confusing you.

Comment: @Barmar: So for this case, `key=int` would also do the trick, at least for the inputs provided.

Comment: Yes, it would. It's HackerRank, they're trying to show "clever" solutions.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar,   key = int doesn't work for all test cases.

Comment: Maybe they're not all integers like in the example you posted.